# Correct way to initialise variables in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I've a mail template in a `.html` file.
This mail will be sent by a node.js server, so I can't use DOM.
The template is loaded like that :

```
fs.readFile('./ressources/template.html', function (err, html) {
if (err) {
    throw err; 
}   
var templateHTML = html ;
```

I'm looking for a proper way to pass kind of variables to the html , as the customer name / date / order id.

Have you any idea of a correct practice to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a template engine, like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Basic example:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

var source = "<p>Hello, my name is {{name}}. I am from {{hometown}}. I have " +
             "{{kids.length}} kids:</p>" +
             "<ul>{{#kids}}<li>{{name}} is {{age}}</li>{{/kids}}</ul>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = { "name": "Alan", "hometown": "Somewhere, TX",
             "kids": [{"name": "Jimmy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "Sally", "age": "4"}]};
var result = template(data);
```

Would render:

```
<p>Hello, my name is Alan. I am from Somewhere, TX. I have 2 kids:</p> 
<ul> 
   <li>Jimmy is 12</li> 
   <li>Sally is 4</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: well seems to almost solve my problem, thanks. Note that handlebars require a string and a whole raw html file won't work because it's not considered as a string

Comment: Maybe you could read the contents of the template file into a string and pass it to Handlebars?

Comment: Yeah or just need to place my html concatened between two quotes. It's not an issue, i wanna just precise this for readers.